# Recyclerview button on specific row - how to capture row id before onclicklistener?

Tags: java, android, android-recyclerview

Below is my adapter class and view code, where I am showing 2 buttons for each of the row. I have setup 2 diff listeners for each button.

New to android, I am not sure, how to get the `getbarCode()` (sort of row id) for the specific row button clicked? (This I want to use to set the barcode b4 I call my webservices). Currently I have hardcoded in code, I want to get it from my Books `getbarCode()`.

Any suggestions?

BookListMyAdapter.java

```
package com.androidatc.customviewindrawer;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.app.ProgressDialog;
import android.support.v7.widget.CardView;
import android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.ProgressBar;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;

import com.loopj.android.http.AsyncHttpClient;
import com.loopj.android.http.AsyncHttpResponseHandler;
import com.loopj.android.http.RequestHandle;
import com.loopj.android.http.RequestParams;
import com.loopj.android.http.TextHttpResponseHandler;

import java.util.List;

import cz.msebera.android.httpclient.Header;

public class BookListMyAccAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<BookListMyAccAdapter.PersonViewHolder> {

    public static class PersonViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder implements View.OnClickListener {

        CardView cv;
        TextView title;
        TextView dueDt;
        final ProgressDialog progress;

        //        ImageView personPhoto;
        public Button searchBtn, renewBtn, returnBtn;

        PersonViewHolder(View itemView) {
            super(itemView);
//            itemView.setOnClickListener(this);
            cv = (CardView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.cv);
            title = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.title);
            dueDt = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.dueDate);
//            personPhoto = (ImageView)itemView.findViewById(R.id.person_photo);
            renewBtn = (Button) itemView.findViewById(R.id.renew_button);
            returnBtn = (Button) itemView.findViewById(R.id.checkin_button);

            renewBtn.setOnClickListener(this);    // <- This lines
            returnBtn.setOnClickListener(this);   // <- This lines

            progress = new ProgressDialog(myActivity);
        }

        @Override
            public void onClick(View itemView) {
                switch (itemView.getId()) {
                    case R.id.checkin_button:
                        String barCode = null, patronId = null;
                        Log.d("TAG", "Success");
//                        Toast.makeText(myActivity.getApplicationContext(), "B4 calling webservice", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                        returnBook(barCode, patronId, progress);
                        break;

                    case R.id.renew_button:
                        barCode = null;
                        patronId = null;
                        Log.d("TAG", "Success");
//                        Toast.makeText(myActivity.getApplicationContext(), "B4 calling webservice", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                        renewBook(barCode, patronId, progress);
                        break;
                }
        }}

        List<Books> books;
    public static Activity myActivity;


        BookListMyAccAdapter(List<Books> books, Activity myActivity) {
            this.books = books;
            this.myActivity = myActivity;
        }

        @Override
        public void onAttachedToRecyclerView(RecyclerView recyclerView) {
            super.onAttachedToRecyclerView(recyclerView);
        }

        @Override
        public PersonViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup viewGroup, int i) {
            View v = LayoutInflater.from(viewGroup.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.item_my_acc, viewGroup, false);
            PersonViewHolder pvh = new PersonViewHolder(v);
            return pvh;
        }

        @Override
        public void onBindViewHolder(PersonViewHolder personViewHolder, int i) {
            personViewHolder.title.setText(books.get(i).title);
            personViewHolder.dueDt.setText(books.get(i).dueOn);
//        personViewHolder.personPhoto.setImageResource(books.get(i).photoId);
        }

        @Override
        public int getItemCount() {
            return books.size();
        }

        public static void renewBook(String barCode, String patronId, final ProgressDialog progress) {
            final int DEFAULT_TIMEOUT = 200000 * 1000000000;

            try {
                // Make RESTful webservice call using AsyncHttpClient object
                AsyncHttpClient client = new AsyncHttpClient();
                client.setTimeout(DEFAULT_TIMEOUT);

                progress.setMessage("Please Wait...");
                progress.setIndeterminate(false);
                progress.setCancelable(false);
                progress.show();

                RequestParams params = new RequestParams();
                params.put("barcode", "B1246857");
                //B1246857
                //B1246855
                params.put("patron", "thida");

//                Toast.makeText(myActivity.getApplicationContext(), "B4 calling webservice", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

                client.post(" http:tron_id=2&item=1", new TextHttpResponseHandler() {
                            @Override
                            public void onSuccess(int i, Header[] headers, String response) {
                                Toast.makeText(myActivity.getApplicationContext(), "Response renew: " + response, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                                Log.d("TAG", "Success");
                                progress.dismiss();
                            }

                            @Override
                            public void onFailure(int statusCode, Header[] headers, String response, Throwable error) {
                                Toast.makeText(myActivity.getApplicationContext(), "Status code :" + statusCode + "errmsg : " + error.getMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
//                                Toast.makeText(myActivity.getApplicationContext(), "Unexpected Error occcured! [Most common Error: Device might not be connected to Internet or remote server is not up and running]", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                                Log.d("TAG", "Failure");
                                progress.dismiss();
                            }

                        }
                );
            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
                //illegal argument exception
                Toast.makeText(myActivity.getApplicationContext(), "Exception Caught" + e.toString(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }

//            progress.dismiss();
//            Toast.makeText(myActivity.getApplicationContext(), "After calling webservice renew", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }
```

item_my_acc.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.v7.widget.CardView
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/cv"
    >

    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:padding="16dp"
        >

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:id="@+id/title"
            android:layout_gravity="left"
            />

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:id="@+id/dueDate"
            android:layout_below="@+id/title"
            />
        <Button
            android:id="@+id/renew_button"
            android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
            android:text="@string/renew"
            android:layout_below="@id/dueDate"
            android:layout_width="90dp"
            android:layout_height="40dp"
            android:layout_gravity="right"/>

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/checkin_button"
            android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
            android:text="@string/checkin"
            android:layout_below="@id/renew_button"
            android:layout_width="90dp"
            android:layout_height="40dp"
            android:layout_gravity="right"/>


    </RelativeLayout>

</android.support.v7.widget.CardView>
```

RecyclerMyAccFrag.java

```
package com.androidatc.customviewindrawer;

import android.app.Fragment;
import android.app.ProgressDialog;
import android.net.Uri;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v7.widget.LinearLayoutManager;
import android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;

import com.loopj.android.http.AsyncHttpClient;
import com.loopj.android.http.AsyncHttpResponseHandler;
import com.loopj.android.http.RequestParams;
import com.loopj.android.http.TextHttpResponseHandler;

import org.w3c.dom.Document;
import org.w3c.dom.NodeList;
import org.xml.sax.InputSource;
import org.xml.sax.SAXException;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.StringReader;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

import javax.xml.parsers.DocumentBuilder;
import javax.xml.parsers.DocumentBuilderFactory;
import javax.xml.parsers.ParserConfigurationException;

import cz.msebera.android.httpclient.Header;

public class RecyclerMyAccFrag extends Fragment
//        implements View.OnClickListener
{

    public List<Books> books;
    public RecyclerView rv;
    public TextView formatTxt, contentTxt, TitleTxt, PublisherTxt, CreatorTxt, AvailabiltyTxt;
    public Button searchBtn,renewBtn, returnBtn;
    ProgressDialog progress;

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.recycler_my_acc, container, false);


//        renewBtn = (Button) rootView.findViewById(R.id.renew_button);
//        returnBtn = (Button) rootView.findViewById(R.id.checkin_button);

//        renewBtn.setOnClickListener(this);
//        returnBtn.setOnClickListener(this);
        String response =getArguments().getString("book_xml");

        rv=(RecyclerView)rootView.findViewById(R.id.rv);

        LinearLayoutManager llm = new LinearLayoutManager(getActivity());
        rv.setLayoutManager(llm);
        rv.setHasFixedSize(true);

//        progress = new ProgressDialog(getActivity());

        readDetails(response);
        initializeAdapter();

        return rootView;
    }


    public interface OnFragmentInteractionListener {
        // TODO: Update argument type and name
        public void onFragmentInteraction(Uri uri);
    }


    public void initializeData(String[] titles, String [] dueDts, int total, String [] barCode){
        books = new ArrayList<>();

        for(int i = 0;i<total;i++)
        {
            books.add(new Books(titles[i], dueDts[i], barCode[i]));
//            Toast.makeText(getActivity().getApplicationContext(), "Title : " + i +
//                    " " + titles[i] + " Due Date: " + dueDts[i], Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }
        Toast.makeText(getActivity().getApplicationContext(), "Total Number of Books Found:"
                + total , Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }

    public void initializeAdapter(){
        BookListMyAccAdapter adapter = new BookListMyAccAdapter(books, getActivity());
        rv.setAdapter(adapter);
    }
```

Books.java

```
package com.androidatc.customviewindrawer;

class Books {
    String title;
    String dueOn;

    public String getBarCode() {
        return barCode;
    }

    public void setBarCode(String barCode) {
        this.barCode = barCode;
    }

    //    int photoId;
    String barCode;

    Books(String title, String dueOn, String barCode) {
        this.title = title;
        this.dueOn = dueOn;
        this.barCode = barCode;
//        this.photoId = photoId;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need `getAdapterPosition()` (https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v7/widget/RecyclerView.ViewHolder.html#getAdapterPosition())

And then get the access (or path the event) `List<Books> books;` in your adapter. 
The easiest way (if you do not need your ViewHolder as static class) is making it just `public class` and so you will get access as the inner class of the adapter.

Comment: Thanks, let me try that.

Comment: Can you tell me - how to " get the access (or path the event) List<Books> books; in your adapter" ? I am not able to find.